# Flutter Load Kotlin instead of Java for my custom plugin

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to use Flutter to develop my own plugin.

I have developed a JAVA class com.talio.travel_app.FlutterNativeImagePlugin

My pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: com.talio.travel_app
        pluginClass: FlutterNativeImagePlugin
      ios:
        package: com.talio.travelapp
        pluginClass: FlutterNativeImagePlugin
```

Then I run the following command

```
flutter pub get
```

The system shows error

```
Couldn't read file LocalFile: 'C:\Users\denni\Documents\Talio\Flutter_App\android\src\main\kotlin\com\talio\travel_app\FlutterNativeImagePlugin.kt' even though it exists.
```

As you can see it point to the kotlin path instead of Java. The file extension loaded as .kt also.
What I expect the correct path is:

```
C:\Users\denni\Documents\Talio\Flutter_App\android\src\main\**java**\com\talio\travel_app\FlutterNativeImagePlugin**.java**
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you developing a plugin in Flutter with Java/Kotlin and not Dart?

Comment: I missed to mention that I have another file \lib\flutter_native_image.dart also. What I am doing is in the following link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: what did you pass in `-a` (or,`--android-language`) when you created your project with `flutter create` command?

Comment: This is a project template which I bought from internet. I imported the project to android studio without typing any command